# Does Hibernate disallow read-only on @Column in embedded ID composite primary key classes (bug?)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Here's the DB design (DDL):

```
CREATE TABLE Countries
(
  iso_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (iso_code)
);

CREATE TABLE Zips
(
  country_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (country_code, code),
  FOREIGN KEY (country_code) REFERENCES Countries (iso_code)
);
```

Here's the Zip class + composite primary key class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Zips")
public class Zip implements Serializable
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private ZipId embeddedId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "iso_code")
    private Country country = null;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class ZipId implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name = "country_code", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String countryCode;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    ...
}
```

Hibernate stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: zips] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:911)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    at tld.zips.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: tld.zips.model.Zip column: country_code (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:675)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:719)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1332)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1835)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902)
    ... 4 more
```

What's this? country_code is mapped as read-only (insertable = false, updatable = false) in the composite primary key class. This works perfectly with EclipseLink! IIRC @Embeddable classes allow @Basic, @Column, @Enumerated, @Temporal, @Lob, and @Embedded on its columns, so this should work. Note the code is JPA 1.0 compatible.

The exception vanishes when putting the insertable = false, updatable = false on the @JoinColumn, but this is not what I want. I prefer my associations to be writable...

Is this a Hibernate bug? I'm using Hibernate 3.6 stable.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, seems like a bug. Anyway, you can do it like this, I suppose. Haven't tried it myself, though.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Zips")
public class Zip implements Serializable
{
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="countryCode", column=@Column(name="country_code", insertable = false, updatable = false))
        @AttributeOverride(name="code", column=@Column("code"))
    })
    private ZipId embeddedId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "iso_code")
    private Country country;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class ZipId implements Serializable
{
    private String countryCode;
    private String code;    

    ...
}
```

Comment: This was not the question! As I wrote, I know this and I don't want it that way: "The exception vanishes when putting the insertable = false, updatable = false on the @JoinColumn, but this is not what I want. I prefer my associations to be writable..." I'm looking for an answer if this is a Hibernate bug. I firmly believe the @Column syntax I posted should work according to the JPA.

Comment: @Kawu: Missed your point, actually. I have updated my post, accordingly. See if this helps.

Comment: While this could work (untested), I believe using AttributeOverrides for mapping is not what JPA was designed for. I read the (bad) book "Java Persistence with Hibernate" which uses a lot of @AttributeOverrides for incomprehensible reasons (ch. 8). I'm trying to map something here, "overriding attribute properties" just appears to be inappropriate IMHO. Again, this works perfectly with EclipseLink. It looks like a bug indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. As a workaround you can place `country` into `ZipId` instead of `countryCode`:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Zips") 
public class Zip implements Serializable 
{ 
    @EmbeddedId 
    private ZipId embeddedId;  
    ... 
} 

@Embeddable 
public class ZipId implements Serializable 
{ 
    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "iso_code") 
    private Country country = null; 

    @Column(name = "code") 
    private String code; 

    ... 
}
```

Comment: Its supported in Hibernate, indeed. But not in JPA, As far as I know. But definitely a valid workaround.

Comment: Yuck. I only go for JPA compatibility. I don't care about Hibernate-specific syntaxes... such code disallows switching JPA provides. Not a good idea.

Comment: @Kawu: Deleted. Will remove this one too, in a while.